# What is the idiomatic way to add a path component from a char iterator without first collecting it?

Tags: rust

E.g.:

```rust
// just an example, can be any Iterator<Item = char>
let iter = "hello".chars();

let mut path = std::path::PathBuf::new();

// works but is inefficient
path.push(iter.collect::<String>());

// does not work:
//   path.push(iter);
// if path were String we could do
//   path.extend(iter)
println!("{:?}", path);
```

Comment: Do you have an arbitrary iterator over `char`, i.e. `impl Iterator<Item = char>`, or are you asking about the `Chars` iterator specidically?

Comment: I have an arbitrary iterator over char, edited the question to make it more clear. My iterator does not implement `as_str()`

Comment: Why do you want to avoid "first collecting it"? This doesn't make too much sense as a requirement to me.

Comment: @SvenMarnach because I am using lazy text transformations to generate a large amount of path components and it seems silly to do a heap allocation for little copy. We are talking about 100-300k more allocations here in a typical run. The point is that one can work with String without causing any temporary allocations. There is an obvious API asymmetry.

Comment: So what you actually want to avoid is unnecessary allocations and copying. This requirement does make sense, but it's a completely different one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go from an arbitrary iterator of characters to a `PathBuf` is to collect the iterator into a `String` first:

```
let path_buf = PathBuf::from(iter.collect::<String>());
```

While this does not literally avoid collecting the iterator first, it will only allocate memory once, when creating the `String`. This memory is reused for the PathBuf, as stated in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#impl-From%3CString%3E):

> Converts a `String` into a `PathBuf`
>
> This conversion does not allocate or copy memory.

Comment: So basically, I should just work with String instead. There seems to be no advantage to using PathBuf in my scenario at all.

Comment: Related documentation bug I filed: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/72349

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple:

```
fn main() {
   let iter = "hello".chars();

   let path = std::path::PathBuf::from(iter.as_str());
   // Or path.push(iter.as_str());
   println!("{:?}", path);
}
```

Comment: Fair enough :) But what if my particular iterator does not implement as_str()?